# Should I use "noisy" or "noisily" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, adverbs

> She set her cup on the glass table, a bit too noisily.

Grammarly changed *noisily* to *noisy*. I think it should be *noisily* because it should modify the verb *set.*

However, there are instances where adjectives are used. E.g. Think different.

What's the correct option here?

Comment: Grammarly made a mistake; noisily is the correct word. Use of adjectives in place of adverbs is non-standard and should be avoided in normal writing.

Comment: FWIW, grammarly does not change noisily to noisy for me, but it also doesn't flag "noisy" as an error.  Have you tried without the comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/noisy), *noisy* can't be used as an adverb. It's always an adjective. So your sentence is grammatically correct.

Grammarly could interpret it a bit differently

> She set her cup on the glass table, [she is (being)] a bit too noisy.

where *noisy* is the only correct choice.

[About Think different](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/is-apples-old-slogan-think-different-grammatically-incorrect)